# Is this bullet really needed in Furstenberg's proof of infinitude of primes?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, prime-numbers

[See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes) .  The bullet I'm referring to is:

> Any union of open sets is open: for any collection of open sets $U_i$ and $x$ in their union $U$, any of the numbers $a_i$ for which $S(a_i, x) \subset U_i$ also shows that $S(a_i, x) \subset  U$.

Couldn't we just say that an arbitrary union of an arbitrary union is an arbitrary union and be done with that part?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're just verifying the axioms for a topology, so the bullet is necessary. You could indeed reword it as you suggest though.

Comment: what I mean was is their more technical proof required when you could simply state the arbitrary union point.  I prefer if it wasn't required.

Comment: I know, I was trying to say: no, not required. They're running through the standard topology from neighborhoods proof.